# MacBook Air with Mavericks does not start up, no disk utility available

Tags: macos, hard-drive, disk-utility

I have a severe problem with a MacBook Air. It does not start up, it hangs at wether a pure white background or white with the Apple logo. I tried to go into disk utility but pressing the option key does not lead anywhere, I do not get to the point where I can choose wether to boot the system or open the disk utility. What can I do? Can I somehow use my other Mac to save the HD of the MacBook Air? How can I install the system fresh? Can I access disk utility somehow using my other Mac?

Answer (score 2):

Did you try to boot with <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> pressed, to boot from the recovery partition? See this [link](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht4718) for details. From here it seems that your MBA does not find a valid OS to continue booting. If the local recovery system is not available, you need a working Internet connection for booting an online version of the recovery system. While in the recovery system, you can troubleshoot the installed system and re-install it, if necessary.

Comment: Yes I tried to boot from the recovery partition but it does not work. The MBA is 2011 version so it seems from your provided link that internet recovery is not available.

Comment: Do you have an external drive with a bootable volume? Do you have a system DVD and an external DVD drive? I think the next step should be to hook your MBA up to a working OS.

Comment: No DVD drive. I could set up a bootable USB drive though. Could a USB drive be a replacement? I have my other MacBook too if that could help.

Comment: In firewire Macs, you could set one up in target mode (Control-T during startup), and the same goes for Thunderbolt Macs (see this link: http://support.apple.com/kb/ph3838). I do not know if your MBA will boot into target mode, but if it does, hooking it up to a second Thunderbolt-equipped Mac would be a good idea. Can you boot with the DVD in the other Mac, using Remote Disk? When you install MacOS on an external USB drive, it will only boot that specific type of Mac used for installing the OS, so using the USB drive might not work, unless you pre prepared it before with a bootable OS

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you've resolved your problem yet but I was getting the same error message when trying to format a 1T external drive.

Did some research today and after about 20 different suggestions I tried a few with no joy.  Finally tried the simplest method that most users said didn't work; use a bootable USB flash installer if you've made one.  Using the recovery partition doesn't work for a lot of people.

Also, how old is your Air?  Did it come pre-installed with Mavericks or did you upgrade from ML?  If you upgraded simply re-download Mavericks from the App store (free).  If Mavericks came already installed then you'll have to use the disc that came with it.  Although another option would be to use your other Mac to re-download Mavericks then simply copy the installer to the Air, putting it into your applications folder (but don't run it).  You can now make your bootable backup.

Anyway, I'm an upgrade from ML so I re-downloaded the Mavericks installer and here's the very short version of how it works.

1. After downloading Mavericks do NOT install.  If it begins automatically simply cancel.  You want the installer unused and located in your applications folder.
2. Make a bootable backup on a 16GB flash drive
3. When finished, shut down computer.
4. Insert USB flash drive.
5. Restart computer and hold down the "Option" key as it goes through the boot process.
6. You'll be given an option to select a boot drive/partition.  Select the USB drive and let it do it's thing.
7. A few choices will come up in a moment.  Select "Disk Utility", the drive will be present and you can now perform whatever functions you need.
8. When finished, reboot in normal mode from you Air and you're problem should be fixed.

If you don't know how to make a bootable USB flash drive, do a quick search.  You'll get plenty of hits and most all of them have the same basic and very easy instructions.  I actually installed the entire Mavericks OS on the flash drive but for reasons not relevant to your question.  If it doesn't work or disk utility is unable to fix your problem then I'd definitely do the fresh install (if you have your data backed up.

This is actually one of the reasons I installed the whole OS on the flash drive.

Good luck.  If anything I said is not something you're capable of doing then we'll try something else.